# Equation of a parabola: Translations and rotation

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I've tried to solve this problem:

Find an equation of the parabola with vertex at point $(1,1)$ whose directrix is the line $x-2y=6$. It has to be solved using translation and rotation (coordinate transformation).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Imagine that you are dealing with the “normal” parabola with vertex at $(1,1)$, namely the one whose directrix is $x=1$. Then ask yourself by what angle does $x=1$ have to be rotated, so as to be parallel to $x=2y+6$. Then apply the [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) corresponding to that particular angle to the algebraic equation of the afore-mentioned parabola.